# .NET issue with foreach loop in order to export result to Excel file

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to solve an issue in my code. It's a `devBooster` code, so pretty similar to `.NET`.
I have a List of objects and I'm looping over each one to populate a stream and finally export this Stream to Excel file thanks to a Template.

This is my foreach loop which populate Stream :

```
foreach (var resultat in ListeDesGroupesNotationsItemVM.Resultat)
{
    string codeAlgo = resultat.CodeAlgo.ToString();
    string codeSegment = resultat.CodeSegment.ToString();

    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 1].Value = resultat.Nom;
    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 2].Value = resultat.IdCMCIC;
    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 3].Value = resultat.NomGac;
    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 4].Value = resultat.Refbilancielle;
    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 5].Value = resultat.Cotation;
    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 6].Value = resultat.Secteur;
    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 7].Value = codeAlgo.IsBlank() ? "" : codeAlgo;
    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 8].Value = codeSegment.IsBlank() ? "" : codeSegment;
    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 9].Value = resultat.DateDerniereCotation;
    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 10].Value = resultat.Statut;
    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 11].Value = resultat.PolePresentateur;
    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 12].Value = resultat.Pays;

    ligne++;
}
```

I have an issue with two fields which are `ENUM field` : `resultat.CodeAlgo` and `resultat.CodeSegment`.

The error message when I try to compile is :

> NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
>   Additional information: The object reference is not defined as an object instance 
>   (sorry for translation)

To my mind, I have to manage NULL field right ?

Thank you by advance

Comment: *I have to manage NULL field right ?* yes, obviously

Comment: Try using `codeAlgo?.IsBlank()` or (from guessing what IsBlank does) replace `codeAlgo.IsBlank() ? "" : codeAlgo;` with `codeAlgo ?? "";`

Comment: Looking at your code I can see multiple places where this could be coming from, the following could be null and trigger this exception, `ListeDesGroupesNotationsItemVM`, `resultat.CodeAlgo`, `resultat.CodeSegment` or`worksheet.Cells[ligne, ...]`

Comment: I tried to comment some part and it works fine all the time except both lines `worksheet.Cells` for `resultat.codeAlgo` and `resultat.codeSegment`

Comment: DevBooster is a group framework. No one will know what it is here. Right now, what you are showing here is only C# using the Tools.Excel Microsoft lib.
My guess is that @DaggeJ is right and you should remove `IsBlank()` function first. Then you should check `resultat`, `resultat.CodeAlgo` and `resultat.CodeSegment` which will throw if null.
Some way to do it : `string codeAlgo = resultat?.CodeAlgo?.ToString();`
string codeSegment = resultat?.CodeSegment?.ToString();
And same for every row.